# How to add the Undo Move feature

Tags: stack

I am trying to build a very simple chess program (Not only the engine) and i am trying to add an "Undo" button. I tried to create a Stack of Boards (A Class i have created earlier in the program) since as we learned that Last In is First Out in stack. After each move i have added the new board to the stack.
I tried to pop the last board (in fact the last 2 elements of the stack both mine and my opponent's next move) but it didnt work.
My question is that is stacks the best way to do the undo move ? Does stacks work on a class i have created ? Or what should i try else since it isn't doing what i expected ?

Comment: stack sounds good for this. What is the behavior in current implementation?

Comment: @neo I have defined a stack : Stack History = new Stack();
At the end of each move : History.Push(board) //board is the array of pieces i have at a certain position
At the button click event i have wrote :   
            History.Pop();
            board = (Board)History.Pop();
            DrawBoard(board);// The function that draw the current board
But nothing is happening when i click the button, the count of the stack changes, but the board is not changing

Comment: Did you check that the boards get saved correctly? If they are, then make sure DrawBoard renders board correctly.